# VSCode debugger pane missing Variables panel

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

Somehow the Variables panel in my VSCode debugger is missing as shown in the picture:
[image: ane]

Is there any way how to turn it on again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Right Click** on any of the views in the Debug Container and select/enable the Variable view.

If you have moved it by accident to a Panel or other View Container, **Right Click** on the header and choose **Reset Location**