# How do I restore the Variables pane in Visual Studio Code (Mac)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-code-debugging

Somehow I've managed to lose the Variables pane when debugging with Visual Studio Code on my Mac. I found the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62905162/vscode-debugger-pane-missing-variables-panel), but I can't right click in the Run and Debug view. The image below is what I'm seeing.

How do I get the Variables pane back?

[image: Run and Debug View]

When I click the three dots, I see this:

[image: Three dots click]

When I right click on one of the titles, I see this:

[image: Click title]

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/q/76144000/11107541 and see if answer there helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already there. Just click on three dots next to gear and check "Variables".

Edit:
Carl Smith accidentaly dragged pane "Variables" to its own container.
See: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/149238

Comment: I tried that. I added a screen image of what I saw after doing it to my original post.

Comment: Didn't you just accidentally drag Variables into owns container?
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/149238

Comment: Thanks - that fixed it! If you'll write that as an answer, I'll upvote and accept it.

Comment: I've edited original answer so you can upvote and accept. I'm glad that I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Choose one of the following:

**- Without right-click:** Click on the ellipsis button in the top right corner, then click on **Variables** (it should be checked).

[image]

**- With right-click:** Right-click on the *title* of any pane (like WATCH or CALL STACK), then click on **Variables** (it should be checked).

[image]

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions, but I don't see the Variables option in either list. I've added images for those cases to my original post.